# python - break string into variables

Tags: python, string

I'm sure this is going to turn out to be a stupid question... I am trying to break up a string like `s = 'P1=12,P2=34,P3=56,P4=78'` into a bunch of individual variables:

```
P1 = 12
P2 = 34
P3 = 56
P4 = 78
```

`s.split(',')` gives me a list `['P1=12','P2=34','P3=56','P4=78']`, which is a start, I think. Any ideas?

Comment: You want to turn these into actual executable Python statements?

Comment: The string will have been spat out by a scientific instrument - in this case the four Ps are the readings on four pressure sensors. I'd like to be able to store the readings in variables which can be frequently updated, and queried by the user.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd go with something like this:

```
d = {}
for assignment in s.split(","):
    name, value = assignment.split("=")
    d[name.strip()] = float(value)
```

This will give you a dictionary mapping the names to the values, which is most probably better than trying to create variable dynamically.  I f you really want to do the latter, you could also do

```
exec s.replace(",", "\n")
```

but this would be really REALLY horrible.

Comment: Thanks for this, a dictionary would certainly do the job. Is there no neat way of breaking a dict up into individual floats?

Comment: @poorsod: Are the names of the variables fixed?  Is it *alyways* the `P1`, `P2`, `P3`. `P4`?

Comment: I'd like to be able to reuse the code for different outputs. For example the same instrument, on a different command, might spit out a string like `CRYO=0.1,1K=0.2,STILL=0.3,MC=0.4`. I'd like to be able to send all sorts of strings like this to the same function which will spit out appropriately-named variables.

Comment: @poorsod: And with this string, you'd like to have a variable called `1K`?  Seems like the dictionary is the way to go.

Comment: See also http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html

Comment: Ah, good point! I hadn't even noticed that it would be an illegal name. Thanks for that; I guess I'll just maintain and update a dictionary containing all the relevant readings.

Answer (score 4):

Just double-split:

```
string = 'P1=12,P2=34,P3=56,P4=78'
d = dict( s.split('=') for s in string.split(',') )
# d == {'P2': '34', 'P3': '56', 'P1': '12', 'P4': '78'}
```

I've put these into a dict, as it may be handier for lookups depending on what you're using the data for.

If you wanted the value as an integer, you could do:

```
d = dict( (k, int(v)) for k, v in (s.split('=') for s in string.split(',')) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
s = 'A=1,B=2,C=3'
d = dict([i.split('=') for i in s.split(',')])
o = '%s = %s' % (', '.join(d.keys()), ', '.join(d.values()))
exec(o)

print A, B, C
# 1, 2, 3
```

Comment: And I thought *my* solution using `exec` was horrible…

Comment: IMHO exec is horrible if you don't know the values its executing, here we're pretty much sure its just unpacking. :)

Comment: You have a point, given that this information comes from some instrument, `exec` might not be as bad as I thought in this case.